# Create a memory block of any type to access and save bits in C

Tags: c, memory-address

Can i create a block of memory in C, say a block of array of 400 ints and then save specific bits in each int space rather than an int?
Im essentially interested in recreating a block of memory space in which chunks of (always 16 bits) bits mean something to me.

What I would want then is memory address of first element and control start of other chunks with a hex offset rather than the start of int in the array for my chunks. Of course all of it would have to be within that original memory space that array has.
On top of that could i do that in the stack?

Also if i have a pointer to an array, can i addresses any of its elements by address as well?

Comment: Yes you can do all that

Comment: Pointers and arrays are isomorphic: `ptr[i] == *(ptr+i)`

Comment: Thank you. So, could I somehow also calculate a memory address based on the type of some element in the array?  Say I know I saved something in 5th bit of 45th element. If I know my starting memory address - how I can calculate that 45th element will a Hex offset of 0x???? ?

Comment: If you want to do bit fidling, you should stick to `unsigned int` rather than `int`. And if you want your chunks of bits to be 16 bits, there is even a datatype for that, `uint16_t`. Other than that, what you are asking for is straight forward. Just declare `uint_t buffer[400]`. The rest is simple pointer arithmetic.

Comment: I went with your recommendation on uint16_t and came up with something like this:`uint16_t fh[20000];
#define TEST_FA_BASE                fh
#define TEST_FA_BASE_ADDR             (&TEST_FA_BASE)
#define MY_BASE_ADDR    (TEST_FA_BASE_ADDR + 0x8F00)` and I get and error while trying to get a pointer  on `(uint16_t *)MY_BASE_ADDR` of  _pointer points outside of underlying object _ I guess my math is off ?

Comment: You should _edit_ your post, and post your code in a code block. Putting your code in a comment is difficult to read, and it may be other parts of your program that are the _real_ issue. It should be downloadable, compilable, and runnable [if a responder chooses to do so].